# A regex with more than one white space

Tags: java, regex, string, split

```
package stringsplit;

public class StringSplit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hello world we are anonymous ";
        String[] s3 = s.split("\\s",2);
        for(String temp:s3){  
            System.out.println(temp);  
        }  
    }        

}
```

**O/P:**

```
hello 
world we are anonymous
```

The above code splits my string into two parts after 1 space character
is encountered by compiler.I then introduced **'\\s+'** so as to split after
2 space characters to get

**o/p:**

```
hello world
we are anonymous
```

But it didn't work.Thanks for you guidance in advanced.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Read the [Split doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)), *"The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied"* so is not what you want to do.

Comment: @Thibaut B : Got it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem using [**String::indexof**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) :

```
String s = "hello world we are anonymous ";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();//----------------------------------------------(0)
String s1 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ", s.indexOf(" ") + 1));//--------------------(1)
String s2 = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ", s.indexOf(" ") + 1) + 1, s.length() - 1);//---(2)
```

---

(0)-Just to make sure that you don't have multiples spaces between the words
(1)-Get the first part from 0 to the second space
(2)-Get the second part from the second space to the end of the string

---

**Output**

```
hello world
we are anonymous
```

Answer (score 1):

According javadoc String [split(regex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and [split(regex, limit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) work like expected. Depending on result you're trying to achieve you can use something of these below:

```java
String s = "hello   world we are anonymous";
String[] s1 = s.split("\\s",2); //result is ["Hello", "  world we are anonymous"]
String[] s2 = s.split("\\s+",2); //result is ["Hello", "world we are anonymous"]
String[] s3 = s.split("\\s+",3); //result is ["Hello", "world", "we are anonymous"]
String[] s4 = s.split("\\s+"); //result is ["Hello", "world", "we", "are", "anonymous"]
```

Comment: i don't think the op want this outputs check the question again and check my answer please :)

Comment: Perfect.Even if you remove '+' answer will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Split doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)), *"The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied"*, so you can't with achieve it with split.
So if you want to split after 2 spaces, you have to write:

```
String s = "hello world we are anonymous ";
int firstSpace = s.indexOf(' ')+1;
int secondSpace = s.indexOf(' ', firstSpace)+1;
String part1 = s.substring(0, secondSpace);
String part2 = s.substring(secondSpace, s.length());
System.out.println(part1); // return "hello world"
System.out.println(part2); // return "we are anonymous "
```